# What is an optimal local sparse structure of a convolutional vision network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, convolution, inception

I was reading the [InceptionNet Paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43022.pdf), where I found quite a few references to developing a `sparse network structure`, but I am not clear on what this means.

An instance of where this has been mentioned:

> The main idea of the Inception architecture is to consider how an **optimal local sparse structure of a convolutional vision network** can be approximated and covered by readily available dense components. Note that assuming translation invariance means that our network will be built from convolutional building blocks.